# Overleaf get content of shared public project

Tags: curl, wget, overleaf

I have this [sample public read-only project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bwzdggmnknpd) which I want to curl/wget to get its content. However, wget and curl results contain message `Cannot grant access; contact the project owner for help`.

Is there any way or program to get html (or, more specifically, [latex](https://www.latex-project.org/)) content of overleaf project?

Comment: It seems that the only solution is to use a headless browser, which is an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: How can you make your "sample public read-only project" be visited by anyone, even for non Log in user?

Comment: @John, that is the question I am asking. This project can be opened in browser without logging in, so it is technically possible

Comment: But it is impossible to change (write) the content, right? And you are looking for read and write possibility without logging in?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested only in getting latex content, without editing it. I agree that it is impossible to edit content without authorization.